# PHP: Need an alternative to eval() for dynamically building multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, eval

Okay, so I know that using eval() isn't great, but I haven't been able to come up with a better solution to my problem, and until recently, there wasn't a performance reason not to use it.  However, I am now passing enough data to the function that it is taking unacceptably long.

The function that is being called is:

```
public static function makeAMultiDimensionalArrayWithSumsBasedOnMultipleFields($inArray, $dimensionFieldNames, $sumFieldNameArray, $staticFieldNameArray = array())
{
    $outArray = array();

    // Just in case the array has indices, sort it so array_pop works as expected.
    ksort($dimensionFieldNames);

    foreach ($inArray as $row)
    {
        // make sure each row in the inArray has all keys specified by $dimensionFieldNames
        $allFieldsPresent = TRUE;
        foreach ($dimensionFieldNames as $keyFieldName)
        {
            if (!array_key_exists($keyFieldName, $row))
            {
                // Note that alternatively we could set the field to a specified default value.
                $allFieldsPresent = FALSE;
            }
        }

        if ($allFieldsPresent)
        {
            $indexString = '';
            $keyFieldNameArrayCopy = $dimensionFieldNames;

            foreach ($dimensionFieldNames as $keyFieldName)
            {
                $indexString .= "['" . $row[$keyFieldName] . "']";
                // lets sum values
                foreach ($sumFieldNameArray as $sumFieldName)
                {
                    eval ('$outArray' . $indexString . '[' . $sumFieldName . '] += $row[' . $sumFieldName . '];');
                }

                foreach ($staticFieldNameArray as $staticFieldName)
                {
                    eval ('$outArray' . $indexString . '[' . $staticFieldName . '] = $row[' . $staticFieldName . '];');
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return $outArray;
}
```

It is being called like this:

```
makeAMultiDimensionalArrayWithSumsBasedOnMultipleFields($data, $dimensionArray, $sumArray, $staticArray);
```

And the variables being passed to the function are similar to:

```
$dimensionArray = array("firstLevelID", "secondLevelID", "thirdLevelID", "fourthLevelID", "fifthLevelID");
$sumArray = array("revenue", "cost", "profit", "sales", "inquires", "cost", "walkins");
$staticArray = array("date", "storeID", "storeName", "productID", "productName", "managerID", "managerName", "salesperson");
```

So I want to rewrite the function so that I'm not using eval() any more.  I've spent a considerable amount of time on this, and feel that it's time to seek some advice.

The goal is to take an array of arrays, and turn it into a multidimensional array based on the dimensions in the $dimensionArray.

I don't want to bore you with too many details right now, so please ask if you need more or have any other questions

Comment: While I am not sure how to pull this off (will look into it later) but still, do we really need a function named `makeAMultiDimensionalArrayWithSumsBasedOnMultipleFields`? You should trim the function name.

Comment: @Whisperity: We have found that descriptive function names are far more beneficial to code maintenance than things like foo() and bar().  But yes, for the purpose of posting here, I probably could have called it something generic.

Comment: @PatrickQ: Descriptiveness is crucial, but there's such a thing as overkill. :)

Comment: I agree with @chaos as this is a bit too much overkill. While the original question is not about what you call your function, it's just a friendly advice to keep it descriptive and short enough to be memorizable. Calling the function `array_multidimensional_multifield_sum_create` would be a better looking approach. Yet again, this is utterly personal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, okay.  First time through I missed your indexing concatenation. Try this:

```
if ($allFieldsPresent) {
    $keys = array();
    foreach ($dimensionFieldNames as $keyFieldName) {
        $keys[] = $row[$keyFieldName];
        // lets sum values
        foreach ($sumFieldNameArray as $sumFieldName)
            self::deepAssign($outArray, $keys, $sumFieldName, $row[$sumFieldName], true);
        foreach ($staticFieldNameArray as $staticFieldName)
            self::deepAssign($outArray, $keys, $staticFieldName, $row[$staticFieldName]);
    }
}

protected static function deepAssign(&$array, $keys, $fieldName, $value, $sum = false) {
    $target =& $array;
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        if (!isset($target[$key]))
            $target[$key] = array();
        $target =& $target[$key];
    }
    if($sum)
        $target[$fieldName] += $value;
    else
        $target[$fieldName] = $value;
}
```

Comment: If you look at the function, you'll see that we add on to $indexString each time through the loop: $indexString .= "['" . $row[$keyFieldName] . "']"; I wish it was that simple.

Comment: That (your edited solution) looks a bit more like what I'm going for.  I'll give that a try tomorrow and let you know how it goes.  Thanks.

Comment: Seems to be a step in the right direction, but `$target =& $target[$key];` in `deepAssign` is throwing the error `Fatal error: Cannot create references to/from string offsets nor overloaded objects`.  I also changed `$target =& $outArray;` to `$target =& $array`, figuring that was a typo.

Comment: I made a few changes and I think I have it working now.  Thanks for heading me in the right direction.  I'll go ahead an mark your answer.

Comment: @PatrickQ: Great!  If you let me know what else you did, I'll edit my answer so it reflects the actual solution (so anybody else who happens along gets good information).  I've corrected the cut-and-paste error you already mentioned (good catch).

Comment: Here's what I ended up with:
`protected static function deepAssign(&$array, $keys, $fieldName, $value, $sum = FALSE)
 {
  $target =& $array;

  foreach ($keys as $key)
  {
   if (!isset($target[$key]))
   {
    $target[$key] = array();
   }

   $target =& $target[$key];
  }

  if($sum)
  {
   $target[$fieldName] += $value;
  }
  else
  {
   $target[$fieldName] = $value;
  }
 }`

The first call to `deepAssign` passes TRUE as fifth parameter.  The second call uses the default of FALSE.

Answer (score -1):

You should look at `create_function()` ([docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) here)